# cannot create name for struct with number

Tags: c, struct

I am trying to create a struct() with some number. Nevertheless, the xcode would not let me.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
typedef struct
{

    char *name;
    float id_no;
    float  0;
    float  1;
    float  2;
    float  3;
}score;

score student [3]={{"C,Joe",999,10.0,9.5,0.0,10.0},
    {"Hernandez,Pete",784,10.0,10.0,9.0,10.0},
    {"Brownnose,Violet",332,7.5,6.0,8.5,7.5}};
```

}

Comment: A variable name can not start with a number

Comment: If `float 0` is legal, what about `int 0 = 1`?

Comment: Hello Carl. Is it possible for me to make a sub struct() so that each number can indicate a score?

Answer (score 0):

identifier can not start with a digit this is covered in the draft c99 standard, we can see this from the grammar for an identifier in section `6.4.2` *Identifiers*:

```
identifier:
    identifier-nondigit
    identifier identifier-nondigit
    identifier digit
identifier-nondigit:
    nondigit
    universal-character-name
    other implementation-defined characters
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far as I know, varaible names can't start with numbers or in this case, be a number. You can use something like _1 instead.